# Disabling form action field from external Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have an html form with `action="result.php`.
Now the problem is, I want my form to only proceed to `result.php` only if certain function inside my javascript returns `true` and i have this to achieve this,

```
function init() {
    var form1 = document.getElementById("test");
    if (validat() == true){
        form1.onsubmit = validatequiz;
    }   
}

window.onload = init;
```

`validat` function either return `true` or `false`, so in the above function i am checking its return value and executing the `onsubmit`, but even if the value return by my `validate()` function is false, I am still redirected to `result.php` which I do not want to do.

The problem is, the action is set inside the html file and i am checking the form in the external javascript file, I am not allowed to use internal javascript within the html file thats why I am having this issue.

Comment: The issue is here that your form is submitting to its action regardless. Your Javascript doesnt stop this. - Your JavaScript needs to stop the submit action. Did you search before asking this - plenty of answers already out there - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=validate+before+submit

Comment: I have searched, and I am already validating everything. Also, most of the answers are related to jquery and i dont understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Javascript doesnt do anything to stop the submit action from completing. To stop the form from submitting you need to explicitly stop it within the Javascript using

```
return false;
```

or

```
event.preventDefault();
```

> Question: How do I prevent the browser's default action in a
>   JavaScript event handler?
>
> Answer: In the early days of JavaScript, to prevent the default
>   response to an event, you could simply refurn false from the
>   respective event handler. For example, returning false from an
>   onsubmit event handler would prevent the browser from submitting the
>   form; returning false from the onclick event handler of a link would
>   prevent the browser from following the link. In most modern browsers,
>   behavior like the above still works; however, now there are many more
>   supported event types, and the actual behavior may depend on the
>   browser and the event type.

- via http://www.javascripter.net/faq/eventpreventdefault.htm